# Разделить строку по нескольким символам-разделителям

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь разделить строку по нескольким символам (`*`, `/`, `-`, `+`)

```
var myString = prompt('string',[]);
 var mySplits = myString.split(код); 
 console.log(mySplits);
```

Пример: входит `4+5-3*2/1`, выходит `4,5,3,2,1`.

Пытался через join и логические операторы, но, видимо, неправильно: не получил нужный результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myString = prompt('string',[]);
var mySplits = myString.split(/\+|-|\*|\//); 
console.log(mySplits);
```

используя регулярные выражения. если нужно опять строку получить, то уже сами, используя join